# MSBuild in a Powershell Script - How do I know if the build succeeded?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am writting a build script with Powershell. The scripts performs various operations such as getting the latest source code off the SVN, backups, etc., and builds the solution using MSBuild:

```
cmd /c C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe "C:\Dev\Path\MyProjct.sln" /p:Configuration=Release
```

After this instruction, I only want to execute the rest of the script if the compilation succeeded. How can I check this?

The project is a web project, so it's not so easy to check for an output, but I would guess some variables would contain the compilation result. Also since I call msbuild with cmd /c, am I going to be able to access these variables?

Comment: I'm just curious... why use a PowerShell script to do the build? Why not use an MSBuild file and use the extension task ibraries out there to do stuff like get from SVN? PowerShell is cool and powerful but to a certain extent you are taking the hard way.

Comment: Well, first thing is that I don't really know MSBuild, but I have an idea that it is a tool for building, and I may struggle to interact with anything else (SVN, WinRAR, ...). For me building is only 5% of the development process and I would think that a scripting language is the most appropriate for the other 95%. But I'm happy to be wrong.

Comment: MSBuild is a great task oriented dependency tool. Using PowerShell enables numerous scenarios and enables product oriented approaches. Check out PSake too, we use that. When you want to extend things, you don't have to drop into C# (MSBuild Tasks). You just add more PowerShell.

Comment: I think that extending your msbuild scripts makes sense for things that are build-related and that have dependency management (e.g. A depends on B; B depends on C and D; D has changed, so now what?).  It's not hard to enable `msbuild /p:SyncAndBuild`, if you want that. If you decide to do more MSBuild, use SO for help. I have way, way too much experience writing complex applications in MSBuild, and would be glad to share.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check the value of `$LastExitCode` right after the call to MSBUILD.  If it is 0, then MSBUILD succeeded, otherwise it failed.

BTW there is no need to use cmd /c.  Just call MSBUILD.exe directly.  We do that in PowerShell build scripts all the time.

Comment: How do you get the error message when you use $LastExitCode?

Comment: You can capture the output of the exe (including stderr).  That is  separate from checking the value of $LastExitCode.

Comment: I use the C# System.Management.Automation.PowerShell object and call the synchronous Invoke method. The problem is that neither the error stream has an entry nor PowerShell.HadErrors is true.

Comment: When you set up the command to execute msbuild.exe try redirecting stderr to stdout e.g. `2>&1`.

Comment: If you run msbuild using `System.Diagnostics.Process` then after the process has exited (ie `Process.HasExited` is true) you can get the exit code using the `ExitCode` property of the `Process` object.

Answer (score 11):

To just check for success/failure, use the automatic variable `$?`.

```
PS> help about_Automatic_Variables


    $?
       Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
    TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.
```

for example:

```
msbuild
if (! $?) { throw "msbuild failed" }
```

Comment: While `$?` works in this case, just be aware that a number of console exes (especially Microsoft tools) invert the exit code logic to return multiple success codes.  So `$?` won't work on those exes.